# C'est une / la première fois

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

J'ai appelé une clinique, mon interlocuteur m'a demandé :

> Avez-vous un dossier avec nous ?

Je lui ai répondu :

> Non, c'est une première fois...

Puis, je me suis demandé si j'avais bien employé l'aricle et je n'ai pas terminé ma phrase. D'après vous, quel article il faut utiliser ici ? D'après des exemples que j'ai trouvés sur Internet, j'aurais dû employer l'article défini, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce que l'article indéfini est aussi correct ?

Comment: « Dossier _avec_ nous » est un anglicisme en français ; autrement, est-ce du québécois ? 
 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dossier+chez+nous%2Cdossier+avec+nous&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdossier%20chez%20nous%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LPH Je ne sais pas, mais j'entends parfois cette formulation.

Comment: Alors, c'est du québécois, probablement introduit via l'anglais.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le contexte, et compte tenu du fait que tu t'es arrêté après « fois », ce que tu as dit était correct et compréhensible pour ton interlocuteur.
Ce n'est cependant pas ce qu'on dirait spontanément dans ce contexte. On définirait cette première fois par exemple avec « que je viens chez vous » et du moment que c'est défini on emploie l'article défini.

- C'est **la** première fois **que je viens chez vous**.

« Une première fois » a plutôt le sens d'« une première expérience ». Par exemple :

> Pour certains enfants partis fin août en colo sur la côte d’Opale, c’était une première fois, et les premières fois, ça ne s’oublie pas. ([La voix du Nord](https://www.lavoixdunord.fr/1063619/article/2021-09-01/une-colo-apprenante-la-mer-inoubliable-pour-48-enfants-du-val-de-sambre))

> Tout le monde aime raconter  ses premières fois. Parfois en soulignent même  une « toute première fois » . Y aurait-il des « toutes premières fois » et des « premières fois » avec une graduation entre les deux ? Ou serait-ce simplement une façon de marquer encore plus la nouveauté… ?
> [...]
> Et s’il  y avait :
> la première fois que je l’ai fait avec mon moniteur,
> la première fois que j’ai conduis<sup>1</sup> sur l’autoroute,
> ([un site personnel](https://www.claireburel.com/redonner-gout-de-permiere-a-vie/))

<sup><sup>1</sup> [sic]</sup>

Answer (score 1):

L'article défini est attendu ici :

> Non, c'est la première fois que je vous contacte.

Tu aurais aussi pu dire :

> Non, c'est mon premier rendez-vous.

> Non, c'est pour un premier rendez-vous.

Comment: Merci, jlliagre. Si la phrase _Non, c'est pour **un** premier rendez-vous._ est possible, _Non, c'est **une** première fois..._ devrait être correcte aussi, non ? S'il n'y a pas de suite _que je vous contacte_ ?

Comment: C'est bien sûr grammaticalement correct, je réponds plus sur l'idiomaticité et là, non. On ne dirait pas ça pour une clinique. Il n'y a qu'une première fois pour toi et une clinique donnée, donc c'est **la** première fois. Avec rendez-vous, une clinique a un premier rendez-vous par patient, donc *un* est utilisé. On ne dirait d'ailleurs pas, *c'est pour le premier rendez-vous* car ça supposerait que les suivants sont déjà prévus.

Comment: _On ne dirait d'ailleurs pas, c'est pour le premier rendez-vous car ça supposerait que les suivants sont déjà prévus._ --- Désolée, je ne comprends pas. Donc, _Non, c'est pour **un** premier rendez-vous_ signifie que l'on ne parle que de ce premier rendez-vous et _c'est pour **le** premier rendez-vous_ sous-entend que le locuteur prévoit d'autres visites ? Mais pourquoi ? Comment les francophones le savent ?

Comment: *C'est pour un premier rendez-vous* se place du côté de la clinique. Elle gère plein de premiers rendez-vous et celui-là n'en est qu'un parmi d'autres. La phrase donne deux informations, *c'est pour un rendez-vous* et *c'est le premier* alors qu'une première fois se place du côté du patient, et il n'y a pas plusieurs *premières fois* donc article défini. On ne peut pas dire *C'est pour une fois* (??) et *c'est la première*.

Comment: *C'est pour le premier rendez-vous* implique qu'il y en aura d'autres. On ne peut pas l'affirmer lorsqu'on prend un premier rendez-vous. Si on dit, *il est arrivé le premier*, c'est forcément qu'il n'était pas tout seul.

Comment: Pour une vaccination avec deux injections, on peut dire : *c'est pour une première vaccination* ou *c'est pour la première vaccination*. Les deux sont idiomatiques.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a deux acceptions importantes du nom « fois ». (([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fois))

> **I.** − [Dans des loc. adv.]
> **A.** − La loc. exprime l'idée de fréquence.
> **1.** [En constr. dir.]
>
> > **I. A.1. a)** Marque l'unicité.
> >
> > **I. A.1. b)** Marque l'itération.

Dans le contexte présenté c'est l'idée d'unicité qui est valide. L'article défini est nécessaire parce parmi toutes les fois possibles toutes sont uniques ([Les articles définis](https://www.francepodcasts.com/2020/08/03/les-articles-definis/)).

Dans le but d'essayer de comprendre ce détail très difficile de l'emploi de l'article, considérons les deux contextes liés suivants.

*1 Contexte impliquant une personne qui s'adresse à une clinique (contexte proposé par la PO)*

> — Avez-vous un dossier ?
> — Non, c'est **la** première fois ?

*Il s'agit de « fois » dans le sens de l'unicité que ce mot peut conférer.*

*2- Contexte associé : la même personne s'entretient avec une amie et lui parle d'une  clinique à laquelle elle s'est adressée, et qui, en fin de compte ne lui a pas donné satisfaction.*

> — Alors tu ne les trouves pas comme il faut ?
> — Non, vraiment, j'y suis allé **une** première fois pour un diagnostic simple et il a fallu quinze jours pour avoir des résultats partiels ; ils m'ont fait revenir **une** seconde fois pour  passer un examen qui n'a été qu'une répétition, et quand j'ai eu les résultats j'ai été avertie qu'ils n'étaient pas immédiatement en mesure de faire la petite opération nécessaire, mais que comme ce n'était pas grave, je pouvais attendre un mois de plus. Eh bien, j'ai changé de clinique et trois jours après la première visite j'étais opérée.

*Il s'agit dans ce second contexte de « fois » dans le sens de l'itération que ce mot peut conférer. On peut, dans ce second contexte, utiliser l'article défini pour la première occurrence, mais, nouvelle énigme, pas pour la seconde ; c'est choix possible. Cependant, la connotation d'itération qu'aurait « Non, c'est une première fois… » dans le contexte de la PO ou le premier contexte ci-dessus a quelque chose de prématuré, comme si la locutrice était soumise à un programme prévoyant plusieurs visites, ou comme si elle s'y soumettait elle-même.*

En conclusion, on doit dire qu'il n'y a qu'une possibilité, et c'est celle avec l'article défini.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Que veut dire _PO_, s'il vous plait ? _contexte proposé par la PO_, _dans le contexte de la PO_ _En conclusion, on doit dire qu'il n'y a qu'une possibilité, et c'est celle avec l'article défini_ --- Mais non, justement, si l'on suit cette idée : _comme si la locutrice était soumise à un programme prévoyant plusieurs visites, ou comme si elle s'y soumettait elle-même_

Comment: @Oreste « PO » est une abréviation que j'ai lue dans au moins une  des réponses de user none et qui ne pouvait être que la traduction de « OP », « original poster » en anglais ;  « OP » doit donc être l'abréviation de « posteur originel ». // Selon cette idée de plusieurs visites programmées, en effet, il me semble aussi que l'article indéfini a un sens, mais dans le contexte que vous décrivez il n'y a aucun arrangement de cette sorte qui ait été conclu entre la clinique et vous. Aussi, l'idée d'itération lorsque vous laissez entendre à un  professionnel de santé que selon une de vos (1/2)

Comment: @Oreste  notions personnelles vous comptez sur plusieurs visites, séances, etc. n'est pas du tout pertinente  dans ce cas précis où vous échangez avec eux les premiers mots, lesquels se trouvent n'être qu'au sujet d'établir s'il existe un contact précédent avec eux ou non. Dans le contexte que vous décrivez, l'article défini devrait  donc être quasiment introuvable, inutilisable. (2/2)