# D'après des / les exemples que j'ai trouvés

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> D'après **des** exemples que j'ai trouvés sur Internet, j'aurais dû
> employer l'article défini, n'est-ce pas ?

([lien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48439/cest-une-la-premi%C3%A8re-fois))

"**Des** exemples" veut dire "parmi tous les exemples que j'ai trouvés sur Internet, seuls quelqu’uns m'ont été utiles". "**Les** exemples" signifie "je considère tous les exemples trouvés". Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 2):

*D'après **les** exemples [...]* signifie bien que tous les exemples consultés qui avaient trait aux articles concordent.

*D'après **des** exemples [...]* signifie que plusieurs exemples appuient le raisonnement, sans présumer qu'il s'agit de la totalité des exemples étudiés ou pas.

On peut bien sûr être plus explicite en disant:

*D'après **tous les** exemples [...]*

ou

*D'après **certains des** exemples [...]*

Comment: _D'après les exemples [...] signifie bien que tous les exemples qui avaient trait aux articles concordent._ --- Tous les exemples (qui parlent des articles) qui se trouvent sur Internet ? Ou tous les exemples (qui parlent des articles) que j'ai vus sur Internet ?

Comment: Tous les exemples consultés bien sûr, puisque c'est explicite : *[...] que j'ai trouvés sur internet [...]*

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

> D'après des exemples que j'ai trouvés sur Internet, j'aurais dû employer l'article défini, n'est-ce pas ?

Non,  « des » peut très bien être utilisé pour une référence à tous les exemples trouvés, mais ce n'est pas un des rôles de « des » de  rendre explicite dans la conversation qu'il s'agit de tous les exemples.

Le problème est une insuffisante familiarisation avec l'article ; il s'agit de l'article indéfini pluriel et non de l'article partitif pluriel. ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3227.php))

[image]

« Les exemples » signifie bien « tous les exemples ».

Comment: Merci, LPH. _Non, « des » peut très bien être utilisé pour une référence à tous les exemples trouvés_ --- Je ne comprends plus rien. Si je parle de tous les exemples que j'ai vus, je devrais employer l'article défini, non ? Ou je dois penser à mon interlocuteur et employer "des" comme dans la formule _J'ai un chien_ ? Parce que mon interlocuteur entend parler de mon chien pour la première fois ? // _Le problème est une insuffisante familiarisation avec l'article_ --- J'ai lu plusiers explications au sujet des articles, croyez-moi. Mais cette notion reste assez vague pour moi...

Comment: @Oreste J'ai parlé le français une grande partie du temps depuis ma naissance et il y a toujours des cas pour lesquels je dois réfléchir et même parfois pour lesquels je ne sais pas ; alors, ne pas désespérer et se rappeler que tout s'améliore en lisant, qu'il est important de laisser faire son effet au travail  interne de correspondance entre forme et contexte qui a lieu sans effort à la lecture.  //  ex. (dialogue) :  {— J'ai acheté des prunes chez l'épicier. — Ah ? Beaucoup ? J'adore les prunes… — Non, il ne leur en restait qu'un kilo et demi et j'ai tout pris. } (1/2)

Comment: @Oreste Il serait drôle que la première personne dise «  J'ai acheté _les_ prunes chez l'épicier. », à moins qu'il y ait eu au préalable une situation qui  garantissait que la seconde personne savait que des prunes allaient être achetées ;  donc la seconde personne utilise « des », pourtant elle  a acheté le tout, toutes les prunes qui étaient chez le marchand. Comprenez-vous un peu mieux ? C'est l'article indéfini. (2/2)

Comment: Oui, merci. On emploie l'article indéfini, du point de vue de notre interlocuteur. // Merci pour l'encouragement. Le problème est que d'habitude  je ne "vois" pas les articles lorsque je lis : je n'en ai pas besoin, je comprends très bien le contexte sans eux et j'imagine que mon cerveau les omet tout bonnement en le considérant inutiles. :) Je dois lire lentement pour m'en rendre compte.

Comment: @Oreste « On emploie l'article indéfini, du point de vue de notre interlocuteur. » : pas idiomatique, il faut deviner ce que vous essayez d'expliquer dans cette phrase.

Comment: @Oreste Voilà ce que dit LBU sur l'emploi de l'article défini : « L'article défini s'emploie devant le nom pour indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un être ou d'une chose connus du locuteur et de l'interlocuteur (c'est l'article notoire de Damourette et Pichon). ».

Comment: _pas idiomatique_ --- OK, merci. Je ne savais pas comment le formuler clairement en russe non plus.